# CAML to query a recurrent event - SP 2010

Tags: caml-query, caml, sharepoint-calendar

I´m using SP CAML Query Helper Online fot getting all the elements of a recurrent event but it only get the general recurrent event. there is possible to get all the days of this recurrent event in differents elements.

Note: I only create the recurrent event, I did not edit any of this.

In Query tab i put the following:

```
<Query>
   <Where> 
      <DateRangesOverlap>
         <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
         <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
         <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
         <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">
            <Year />
         </Value>
      </DateRangesOverlap>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

In View Fields tab:

```
<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />

<FieldRef Name="EndDate" />

<FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />

<FieldRef Name="RecurrenceData" />
```

In View Attributes tab:

ExpandRecurrence="True"

Comment: In Which element do you need all the days of your recurrent event?

Answer (score 0):

Using below code you will get recurring events as distinct items using `SPServices`.

```
var startDate = "2012-05-12T12:00:00Z"; // Our example will show the month of May 2012

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "My Calendar",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
        "</ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query>" +
            "<Where>" +
                "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                    "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
                        "<Month />" +
                    "</Value>" +
                "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
            "</Where>" +
            "<OrderBy>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
            "</OrderBy>" +
        "</Query>",
    CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions>" +
            "<CalendarDate>" + startDate + "</CalendarDate>" +
            "<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>" +
            "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
        "</QueryOptions>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var $node = $(this),
                fADE = $node.attr("ows_fAllDayEvent") || 0,
                thisADE = (fADE == 0),
                thisID = $node.attr("ows_ID"),
                sepID = thisID.indexOf(';#'),
                thisTitle = $node.attr("ows_Title"),
                thisRecurrence = $node.attr("ows_fRecurrence"),
                thisDesc = $node.attr("ows_Description");
            if (sepID != -1) thisID = thisID.substring(0,sepID);
            var thisUrl = "DispForm.aspx?ID=" + thisID,
                thisClass = thisTitle.replace(" ","").substr(0,10).replace(",","").replace(" ","") + thisID,
                thisRD = $node.attr("ows_RecurrenceData");                                                        

            // if working with FullCalendar or building an events object for another purpose...
            events.push({
                title: thisTitle,
                start: $node.attr("ows_EventDate"),
                end: $node.attr("ows_EndDate"),
                allDay: thisADE,
                url: thisUrl,
                description: $(thisDesc).text()
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Please refer the below link for more information.

[Use SPServices to Get Recurring Events as Distinct Items](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/26/use-spservices-to-get-recurring-events-as-distinct-items-aspx/)

Comment: But is there any way to do the query with SP CAML Query Helper Online?

Comment: Please use this tool to build the query...https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Have you got it working for you?

Comment: This is the tool that I am making reference